# how do you wire in an emergency stop into 12v

Tags: diesel, switches

Just wondering how you would wire in an emergency 'E' stop into a 12 volt or 24 volt diesel engine??

Do you have to wire into the ignition circuit or the fuel solenoid to prevent any chance of the engine running on?

Answer (score 2):

Since diesel engines don't have an ignition system, you will have to control the fuel shut-off mechanism in the injection pump.

Note that some engines (my Cummins 6BT, for example) require power on the solenoid to run, while others (such as a Ford Lehman I had) require power on the solenoid to stop.